# getLoaderManager in Fragments is deprecated

Tags: android, android-support-library, loader

After update I found that `getLoaderManager` is deprecated but I can't find that should I use instead of.
How to get `LoaderManager`? Or what should I use instead of `Loader`s?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders

Comment: @AngusTay, thank you, I understood the problem in English version. Just Google decided that it's not an important information to show in Russian site version that Loaders are deprecated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Loaders have been deprecated as of Android P (API 28). The recommended option for dealing with loading data while handling the Activity and Fragment lifecycles is to use a combination of ViewModels and LiveData.ViewModels survive configuration changes like Loaders but with less boilerplate. LiveData provides a lifecycle-aware way of loading data that you can reuse in multiple ViewModels.

Answer (score 6):

getLoaderManager has been deprecated, use LoaderManager getInstance instead:

```
LoaderManager.getInstance(this).initLoader(0, null, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

The deprecated `getLoaderManager` has been replaced with `getSupportLoaderManager`. Try:

```
getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_NOTES, null, this);
```

Works for me in API 28.